# Help me optimize a query for random records

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a query for random records that's mad inefficient because it's ordering by RAND() and creating a temporary table each time it's called.  Also, this means that it cannot be cached.  It is also joined to another table which adds processing time and complicates things a little.  So, help me optimize the following:

```
SELECT     listings.id, listings.price, listings.seller_id, sellers.blacklisted
FROM       listings
INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = listings.sellers_id
WHERE      listings.price > 100
AND        sellers.blacklisted = 0
ORDER BY   RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

One way to start going about this is to run one query that returns a COUNT() of the possible listings, then a second query (or 4 others if it's to be truly random) with an offset set within RAND()*COUNT.

How would you approach this?

Comment: So how does one cache random records?

Comment: How is that creating a temporary table?

Comment: A random select can't be completely cached, however, the above statement will SELECT all 10,000 listings, then order them randomly THEN limit it to 4 records.  Wildly inefficient.

Comment: I feel like a few things could be cached:
1) COUNT to get the total number of listings for use in a SELECT WHERE listings.id = RAND() * MAX
2) Maybe there's a way to create a cachec table of all listings with that JOIN and WHERE condition.  Then all that's needed is a SELECT for random id in that table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `listings` is indexed on id:

If your id is an integer:

```
SELECT     listings.id, listings.price, listings.seller_id, sellers.blacklisted
FROM       listings
INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = listings.sellers_id
WHERE      listings.price > 100
AND        sellers.blacklisted = 0
AND        listings.ID LIKE CONCAT(CEIL(RAND() * 100),'%')
LIMIT 4
```

and if it's ascii

```
SELECT     listings.id, listings.price, listings.seller_id, sellers.blacklisted
FROM       listings
INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.id = listings.sellers_id
WHERE      listings.price > 100
AND        sellers.blacklisted = 0
AND        listings.ID LIKE CONCAT(CHAR(CEIL(RAND() * 100)),'%')
LIMIT 4
```

basically my advice to speed things up is dump the order by. On anything over a few records you're adding measurable overhead.

ps please forgive me if concat can't be used this way in mqsql; not entirely certain whether it'll work.

Comment: Better to do integer `RAND()` on ID?

Comment: @Gustav, no idea! Rand() gives a number between 0 and 1; I was just giving the random number a chance of being anything. It doesn't really matter; as long as you get rid of the order by. I was trying to force an range scan of the primary key ( I assume ) as well to speed things up as well.

Comment: It's the way to do it. I meant only if ID is an integer instead of varchar.

Comment: This would work alright if you know that there will always be > 100 records but also wouldn't be choosing from the full range of possible records.  I suppose you could to a 'SELECT COUNT()' before that statement to get the max and then replace the * 100 with the result.